# Use string to extract a list with same name as the string

Tags: r

I have vectors named "abc12" and "abc13" which has a list of numbers that I want to use. I am trying to paste the lengths of these vectors (which are 12 and 13) in string "abc" then use this string named abc12. By using this string "abc12" I want to extract the vector **abc12** out of this string "abc12". How can I go about doing this in R?

Comment: `?get` like `get("abc12")` maybe. Though if you're using `get` and `assign` you've probably gone awry somewhere.

Comment: thanks    _________________________

Comment: You can use `mget` for multiple elements i.e. `mget(ls(pattern = "abc\\d+"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, we created vectors, 'v1' and 'v2'

```
v1 <- 1:12
v2 <- 1:13
```

Then, we use `assign` the values of the vectors  to create new objects.

```
assign(paste0("abc", length(v1)), v1)
assign(paste0("abc", length(v2)), v2)
abc12
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

If we need to extract the strings "abc12", "abc13", use `ls` with `pattern`

```
ls(pattern = "abc\\d+")
#[1] "abc12" "abc13"
```

Or another option is `deparse/substitute`

```
deparse(substitute(abc12))
#[1] "abc12"
```